# Error in SQL syntax Can seem to find the right query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, vb.net

Im having trouble I cant seem to make my sql query right

```
                Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE userscanner SET Username ='" & txtbox_username.Text & "',Password='" & txtbox_password.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & lbl_id.Text & "')", Connection)
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Profile Successfuly Saved")
                Me.Close()
```

but i have a error that says " you have an error in your sql  syntax; check the manual that coressponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

BTW I use XAMPP and MYSQL as database

Comment: Remove `)` from `& "')"`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com! :-) The number of braces in your statement is not balanced. There is an extra brace at the end of your statement. That is what the error message is trying to tell you.

Comment: you should really use a parameterized query to avoid sql injection. and, as others have said, you do not need the `)` in the `& "')"` after `lbl_id.Text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an excess ')'

Correction:

```
            Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE userscanner SET Username ='" & txtbox_username.Text & "',Password='" & txtbox_password.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & lbl_id.Text & "'", Connection)
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Profile Successfuly Saved")
            Me.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE userscanner SET Username ='" & txtbox_username.Text & "',Password='" & txtbox_password.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & lbl_id.Text & "'", Connection)
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Profile Successfuly Saved")
        Me.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be including a ')' closing paranthesis with no opening one, when constructing your sql statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove ')'.

```
Dim command1 As New MySqlCommand("UPDATE userscanner SET Username ='" & txtbox_username.Text & "',Password='" & txtbox_password.Text & "' WHERE ID = '" & lbl_id.Text & "'", Connection)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Parameterized Update Query